# Weird colors upon OBJ import

Tags: texturing, import, obj

I imported this asset into blender as an *obj from the unpacked folder.
https://www.turbosquid.com/3d-models/sony-trinitron-kv-13tr28-1995-3d-1564778

upon import it looked like this, however:
[image]

Also, when i imported the *obj from outside the unpacked folder, it looked like this.

[image: almost invisible dark grey on slightly lighter grey; totally opaque, though]

Also also, this is a screenshot from the only texture folder that came with the asset:
[image: MAPS folder that came with the asset]

Disclaimer: Yes, I am new to blender so this requires the utmost patience from you veterans.

Comment: "*When i imported the *obj from outside the unpacked folder*" because blender can't find the associated files with included image textures and/or material mtl files

Comment: Yeah, i did this to maybe narrow down the search for the error, not cause I was expecting success with importing just the *obj ;). Edited the post to show the 'MAPS' folder that holds all the texture-files.

Comment: First of all, unpack all files. Then, if the materials have correctly assigned textures and they still don't show up, go to the menu _File_ > _External Data_ > _Find Missing Files_. Then navigate to the folder where the files are located and click on the button "Find Missing Files". If they don't show up now, maybe the materials aren't setup correctly and you have to do it manually. If you are a complete beginner, I would recommend to watch some tutorials on materials and texturing.